# Obtener la propiedad de un objeto si tengo el nombre de la propiedad como string

Tags: javascript

Tengo un objeto de objetos. Representa cada lenguaje de programación y su respectivo color (fuente: [github](https://github.com/ozh/github-colors/blob/master/colors.json)) :

```
colors = {
  '1C Enterprise': {
    'color': '#814CCC',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=1C-Enterprise'
  },
  'ABAP': {
    'color': '#E8274B',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=ABAP'
  },
  'ActionScript': {
    'color': '#882B0F',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=ActionScript'
  },
  'Ada': {
    'color': '#02f88c',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=Ada'
  }
  //...
}
```

¿Cómo se haría una función con *Javascript* la cual, recibiendo el nombre de un lenguaje, me devolviese su color. Por ejemplo `devolverColor('Ada')` devolviese `#02f88c`

Comment: La variable `colors` está definida así en tu código o lo estás obteniendo desde un recurso web?

Comment: La he definido yo en mi código

Comment: Entonces no es un JSON. Es simplemente un objeto. JSON sería si estuviese como un string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La función así estaría muy simple:

```
function getColorNotSafe(languaje){
  return colors[languaje].color;
}
```

**PERO** no es segura.

Veamos:

#### Aquí TODO BIEN

```js
var colors = {
  '1C Enterprise': {
    'color': '#814CCC',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=1C-Enterprise'
  },
  'ABAP': {
    'color': '#E8274B',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=ABAP'
  },
  'ActionScript': {
    'color': '#882B0F',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=ActionScript'
  },
  'Ada': {
    'color': '#02f88c',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=Ada'
  }
};

console.log(getColorNotSafe("Ada"));

function getColorNotSafe(languaje){
  return colors[languaje].color;
}
```

#### Aquí NO TODO BIEN

El problema es que esta función permite que le pasemos lo que sea. ¿Quién va a controlar eso? Supongamos que se intente buscar `Ada5`:

```js
    var colors = {
      '1C Enterprise': {
        'color': '#814CCC',
        'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=1C-Enterprise'
      },
      'ABAP': {
        'color': '#E8274B',
        'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=ABAP'
      },
      'ActionScript': {
        'color': '#882B0F',
        'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=ActionScript'
      },
      'Ada': {
        'color': '#02f88c',
        'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=Ada'
      }
    };

    console.log(getColorNotSafe("Ada5"));

    function getColorNotSafe(languaje){
      return colors[languaje].color;
    }
```

#### Aquí MEJOR

Entonces, conviene escribir una función segura, que devuelva al menos `null` si no encuentra la propiedad que se le está pasando:

```js
var urlGit='https://github.com/trending?l=';
var colors = {
  '1C Enterprise': {
    'color': '#814CCC',
    'url': urlGit+'1C-Enterprise'
  },
  'ABAP': {
    'color': '#E8274B',
    'url': urlGit+'ABAP'
  },
  'ActionScript': {
    'color': '#882B0F',
    'url': urlGit+'ActionScript'
  },
  'Ada': {
    'color': '#02f88c',
    'url': urlGit+'Ada'
  }
};

console.log(getColor("Ada"));
console.log(getColor("Ada5"));

function getColor(languaje) {
  var resultado=colors.hasOwnProperty(languaje) ? colors[languaje].color : null;
  return resultado;
}
```

---

### Otro plus

Nótese que se podría hacer un re-juego interesante para la `url`: sería combinar el parámetro recibido con la variable `urlGit`... no me he atrevido a hacerlo porque los valores no están normalizados en el caso de la primera opción. Pongo esta nota para abrir esa posibilidad, buscando simplificar el código, haciéndolo menos repetitivo.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo no te entendí nada... ¿te refieres a la función `getColor`, al último código?

Comment: Me equivoqué de respuesta. Era la de @Einer. Disculpa A.Cedano.

Comment: Eso sí. Sería conveniente declarar la variable `resultado` dentro de la función (utilizando var). Si no también estará definida en el contexto de window. Saludos!

Comment: Listo. Gracias @JoseHermosillaRodrigo. Lo tendré en cuenta para próximas ocasiones, buena observación.

Answer (score 4):

Yo pondria:

```js
 var colors = {
        '1C Enterprise': {
          'color': '#814CCC',
          'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=1C-Enterprise'
        },'ABAP': {
          'color': '#E8274B',
          'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=ABAP'
        },'ActionScript': {
          'color': '#882B0F',
          'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=ActionScript'
        },'Ada': {
          'color': '#02f88c',
          'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=Ada'
        }
       };

 console.log (colors['ActionScript'].color);
```

Podes hacer una función y le pasas como parámetro el lenguaje, pero al igual q el otro ejemplo q te enviaron recién, tenes q asegurarte de q este bien escrito el lenguaje.

Comment: ¿Probaste que funcione? Podrías usar un snippet con el botón `<>` en el editor y ejecutar tu código

Comment: Si te soy sincero ... no se como hacer ejemplos. Lei la documentación pero solo vi q funcione con HTML. No se como hacer para testear con JS.

Comment: funciona con HTML, pero no es necesario que haya una página. Simplemente hay que poner el código en la parte de JavaScript. Se puede usar `console.log()` para imprimir lo que quieras... Si no te queda claro, podés preguntar cómo usarlo en [meta]

Answer (score 2):

Intenta accediendo a las propiedades de un objeto utilizando acceso por indice `objeto[nombrePropiedad]`.

Ejemplo:

```js
colors = {
  '1C Enterprise': {
    'color': '#814CCC',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=1C-Enterprise'
  },
  'ABAP': {
    'color': '#E8274B',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=ABAP'
  },
  'ActionScript': {
    'color': '#882B0F',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=ActionScript'
  },
  'Ada': {
    'color': '#02f88c',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=Ada'
  }
};

console.log(colors["Ada"].color);
console.log(colors["1C Enterprise"].color);
```

Solo asegurate de enviarle el nombre de la propiedad correctamente.

Tambien puedes definir una funcion que te retorne el color directamente si lo que necesitas:

```js
colors = {
  '1C Enterprise': {
    'color': '#814CCC',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=1C-Enterprise'
  },
  'ABAP': {
    'color': '#E8274B',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=ABAP'
  },
  'ActionScript': {
    'color': '#882B0F',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=ActionScript'
  },
  'Ada': {
    'color': '#02f88c',
    'url': 'https://github.com/trending?l=Ada'
  }
};

colors.devolverColor = function(lenguaje){
   return (this[lenguaje].color);
}

console.log(colors.devolverColor("Ada"));
```

Comment: Cuidado! Si defines la propiedad como lo haces en el segundo ejemplo, la defines como enumerable. Al hacer un for..in u Object.keys será una propiedad más. Puedes usar Object.defineProperty de esta forma: `Object.defineProperty(colors, 'devolverColor', {enumerable: false, get(lenguaje){ return this[lenguaje].color}})`