# ¿Cómo recorrer listas de valores dentro de una lista JSON? "AYUDA"

Tags: json

Solicitando de su ayuda,tengo una lista de listas en JSON que guardo en una cadena "resultado" y necesito recorrer para acceder a algunos valores en concreto, Solo he podido acceder a el id de la siguiente manera:
resultado.id   (ESTO EN GROOVY, quiero pensar que no tiene mucho que ver)
Código del JSON:

```
resultado = {
    "id": 51,
    "inique-id": 51,
    "properties": {
        "firstname": {
            "value": "Test01",
            "versions": [
                {
                    "value": "Test01",
                    "value-2": "Test02"
                }
            ]
        },
        "events": {
            "value": "0",
            "versions": [
                {
                    "value-events": "0",
                    "description": "CALCULATED"
                }
            ]
        }
    "merge-audits": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Puede q esta pregunta tenga una respuesta en [Obtener la propiedad de un objeto si tengo el nombre de la propiedad como string](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/131984/60415)

Comment: http://groovy-lang.org/ ? si es asi ponele los tags correspondientes

Comment: Les agradezco mucho, esa fue la solución ya llevaba desde muy temprano con esto, así quedo: def res1 = resultado['properties'] def res2 = res1['firstname'].value